# Wrong button executes the method="post"

Tags: post

How do I prevent "button1" from executing the emailform.php action?

I have three buttons on my page; two of which are supposed to just make sure the text boxes are not blank and the third one is a "submit" button that is supposed to email me the form results via a emailform.php action.  The problem is that when I click on button 1 to validate the text boxes, it does that correctly but then tries to email the form.

```
<form name="surveyform" action="/emailform.php" method="post">
<button id="button1" onclick="return validate_question1()">Go to question 2</button>
<button id="button2" onclick="return validate_question2()">Go to question 3</button>
<input  name="submit" value="submit" class="submit" type="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -- set the type:

```
 <button type ="button" id="button1" onclick="return validate_question1()">
```

Might need to see the onclick function.

Comment: *Why* does that work? You'd think the default type of button would be 'button', not 'submit'.

Comment: yeah you probably would haha. default is submit though.